# What are some practical tips to easily change tunings on stage?

Tags: electric-guitar, tuning, band

I realize this requires having multiple guitars.

I'm personally aiming to use 3 different and diverse tunings for my band, but my bassist seems to differ.
Obviously I'm gonna buy more guitars. :) He should too.

But that would require having 4+ guitars on stage?

How do people generally deal with this? You constantly have to plugin/unplug instruments, it's kind of tricky. Are there any fast ways to switch on stage?

Update: i need more guitars because some tunings revolve around drop D, but some C standard. Don't wanna mess my guitar setup.

Comment: Why do you need to change your tuning so many times? Also as a side note if it's not an exotic tuning like Open G a capo might come in handy.

Comment: Take a look at the Line 6 Variax (no endorsement intended, though I do like them). They have fully programmable tunings which you can recall with a knob on the guitar or foot switch.

Comment: Well, your bassist is primarily playing notes, not chords, so retuning is far less of an issue. <-- assuming your "retuning" is defined as changing the open-string pitches, not the note frequency (e.g. A = 440 to A= 434)

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: you don't need multiple guitars, you can get an AutoTuner for guitar which can re-tune for you instantly.

Comment: Loosely related: http://music.stackexchange.com/q/20748/6556

Comment: Nah, it's not. Sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In practice I've come across 4 solutions for using several different guitars (that need to go into one amp, I suppose):

- use a router switch (e.g. [this one](http://www.musiciansfriend.com/amplifiers-effects/morley-abc-selector-combiner-switch)). In this case you use one cable per guitar.
- use a mute pedal (you could use a tuner pedal which mutes the output when switched on). Here you would use the same cable for all guitars.
- use a volume pedal set to silent when changing guitars (as already suggested in Alexander Troup's answer). Also here you would use the same cable for all guitars.
- go wireless: one bodypack (transmitter) per guitar and one receiver for all.

**EDIT:** BTW, if it's only about dropping the low E to D, you can also use something like the [Sperzel "D-Thing" Tuner](http://www.guitarpartsresource.com/tuners_sperzeldthing.htm).

Comment: Great! I like all the options but the router switch.

Answer (score 3):

*Depending on what you're willing to spend, there are a few [auto tuning devices](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3gUbr5G9zM) that can be used on one guitar which re-tunes Extremely fast, but I've not looked into them so it's worth more research on each one.*

As far as Jacks, you can get some [magnetic switchers](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13526_3-9997510-27.html) that might come in handy.  Or you could go for the classic where you just switch leads.  You could get a volume pedal to turn to 0 before every switch too, making it indiscernible.

I think you can also get wireless switchers where you have multiple jacks (one per guitar) and a channel switcher on the amp.

Hope that gives some ideas :)

Comment: I just looked into the magnetic switchers that you linked to and I don't believe they are actually for sale by Belkin.  I couldn't find anything other than a press release.  However, I did find these http://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-magnetic-guitar-cable.html Sounds like a great idea that I may need to purchase at some point.

Comment: Silent jacks - used them for years - made by Neutrik. They turn off as you plug/unplug.Buy attached to a lead, or replace on a ready made lead.

Comment: @Tim I'll have to try them out!

Comment: I use several,on stage, and in the studio. They are also invaluable for teaching, in that each student doesn't wreck my speakers at changeover time !

Comment: I like the silent jack idea, guys.

Answer (score 2):

The old folksinger Joni Mitchell had about 55 tunings that she would regularly use in performance. When she no longer wanted an 18-wheeler to carry 55 guitars on tour she went to the Roland VG-8 guitar processing system which stored all her guitar tunings.  Joni Mitchell would play on a strat so under monitored situations the difference between the way that the strings are really tuned and how they come out of the unit wouldn't be so bad. (Source: http://www.jonimitchell.com/library/view.cfm?id=38)

The Roland guitar processor is now up to the VG-99 (http://www.rolandus.com/products/details/849/specs/) but try before you buy.  The last time I tried a VG, there was some latency on the low notes and I really didn't like the electronic sound of the notes produced. But to each his own.